Migrate to .NET 9, Bad request (400) on controllers and API methods
In .NET 9 you may give error 400 on passing null to a controller with non-nullable parameters of the controller's method. There are two ways to solve it. In my case, my client was sending the 'searchString' and 'orderBy' parameters as null, and no problem in .NET 8. But after migrating to .NET 9, the client gets an error

Bad request 400 - the field x is required

[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(int pageNumber, int pageSize, string searchString, string orderBy, int productId = 0)
{
    if (UserId == null)
        return BadRequest();

    var products = await _mediator.Send(new GetUserConfigQuery((Guid)UserId, pageNumber, pageSize, searchString, orderBy)
    {
        ProductId = productId,
    });
    return Ok(products);
}


Don't write the solution in the question. Instead, write it as the answer.

I don't see anything in the changelog of (ASP.)NET Core 9 that suggests this behavior has changed. Can you link the relevant changes?

The action's parameters are not-null, which means they're required. The OpenAPI spec generated by this action will say as much.

I solved it with these tricks:

Make the parameters nullable
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAll(int pageNumber, int pageSize, string? searchString, string? orderBy, int productId = 0)


Or if you don't want to modify a lot of codes as solution 1, then force the router to accept null as before in dotnet 8
builder.Services.AddControllers(o =>
{
    //o.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true;
    o.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true;
}).AddValidators();



It worked for me, hope help you too ;)
